# Android okhttp: Getting randomly java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: 1.1 200 OK

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, okhttp

when using androids URL and HttpUrlConnection to send a GET request to a backend point, it sometimes (1 out of 10) occurs, that the request fails due to:
java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: 1.1 200 OK

As said this only happens somtimes, I tried 3 different backends (one of them self hosted) and it still occurs.

```
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        URL url = new URL(callUrl);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        con.setReadTimeout(4000);
        con.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you try to use Retrofit to do this requests ?

Comment: I don't know, haha, I can try, but does it use a different http lib?

Comment: Are you using JSON ?

Comment: @FelipeJunges as response type? Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all, this is the API references link:
>   http://square.github.io/retrofit/

So, go to: 
**File > Project Structure** , after opened, **in modules - app**, go to tab **Dependencies**.

[image: My Project Depedencies]

Click on the **+** symbol and add library

Search and add this library: `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.30`, and I highly recommend you to use Jackson too, if you want it, add this library to: `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.3.0`

After all depedencies and building, let's go to the code.

I created a **RetrofitInitialization** class with this code:

```
public class RetrofitInicializador {
public RetrofitInitialization() {

String url = "localhost:8080/webservice/";
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create()).build();
}
}
```

We need to create a service too, so, I created a service class called:
**ObjectService**

```
public interface ObjectService {

    @POST("post/example")
    Call<Object > postexemple(@Body Object object);

    @GET("get/example/{id}")
    Call<Object> getexemple(@Path("id") Integer id);

}
```

The Object is your model that you want to receive or send.
After this, add your service into the RetrofitInitialization, after the constructor.

Similar this:

```
public ObjectService getObjectService() {
    return retrofit.create(ObjectService.class);
}
```

In your Activity or anywhere you want to get this informations, do something like this:

```
 private void loadFromWS(Object object) {
        Call<Object> call = new RetrofitInicializador().getObjectService().postexemple(object);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
                Object response = response.body();

               // DO your stuffs
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(AgendaActivity.this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Edit: Forget to tell, I used this on WS REST server (to be more specific: JAX-RS and Jersey WS)